# How to call JSNI method from JSNI method in GWT

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, jsni

Is it possible to call native method from another native method in the same class in this way?

```
public native JavaScriptObject mySECONDJsniMethod(String name) /*-{
        //..
        return secondVar;
}-*/;

public native JavaScriptObject myFIRSTJsniMethod(String name) /*-{
        var secondVar = mySECONDJsniMethod(name);
        //..
        return firstVar;
}-*/;
```

In my Chrome Console it returns: `Uncaught TypeError: mySECONDJsniMethod is not a function` .
Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Within the JSNI for myFIRSTJsniMethod(), use the normal JSNI syntax for calling a Java method.

For example, if these two methods are in the class `com.mycompany.Test`, you could call mySECONDJsniMethod() like so:

```
public native JavaScriptObject myFIRSTJsniMethod(String name) /*-{
    var secondVar = this.@com.mycompany.Test::mySECONDJsniMethod(Ljava/lang/String;)(name);
    //..
    return firstVar;
}-*/;
```

See the GWT documentation on [Accessing Java Methods and Fields from JavaScript](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html#methods-fields) for more information.

**EDIT:** Here is a complete compilable example:

```
package com.mycompany.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptObject;

public class SO26277049 implements EntryPoint {

    @Override
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        final JavaScriptObject firstVar = myFIRSTJsniMethod("hello world!");
    }

    public native JavaScriptObject mySECONDJsniMethod(String name) /*-{
        var secondVar = {
            name: name
        };
        return secondVar;
    }-*/;

    public native JavaScriptObject myFIRSTJsniMethod(String name) /*-{
        var secondVar = this.@com.mycompany.client.SO26277049::mySECONDJsniMethod(Ljava/lang/String;)(name);
        $wnd.alert(secondVar.name);
        var firstVar = secondVar;
        return firstVar;
    }-*/;
}
```

Comment: Now it returns that *mySECONDJsniMethod* is undefined @Daniel Trebbien.

Comment: @django: What is the fully-qualified class name containing these two methods? You need to use that instead of `com.mycompany.Test`. I have edited my answer to give a full example.